# Using javascript to change width of multiple images with same id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with multiple images with the same `id`, I want to use javascript to size each of these depending on their original size. It only seems to check the first instance of the image and not the others, is there any way to get this working on all images?

```
<img id="myImg" src="compman.gif" width="100" height="98">
<img id="myImg" src="compman.gif" width="49" height="98">

<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("myImg").width;
var yourImg = document.getElementById('myImg');
if(x < 50) {
    yourImg.style.height = '100px';
    yourImg.style.width = '200px';
}
</script>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique. You don't have classes on the images, you have ID. Perhaps you wanted `class="myImg"`

Comment: As @Huangism said, IDs must be unique. See [html spec 7.5.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this isnt working is that `getElementById` is intended to find and return a single element with that Unique element Id. If you have two elements with the same Id, only the first is returned.

So to start off with you would need to make sure that your images share a common class, instead of the same Id, like so:

```
<img class="myImg" src="compman.gif" width="100" height="98">
<img class="myImg" src="compman.gif" width="49" height="98">
```

Then instead of using `document.getElementById` you should use `document.querySelectorAll()` which will return all elements which match the selector (as a NodeList). [document.querySelectorAll on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

Then you can turn the `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll` into a normal array of images using `Array#slice` [Array#slice on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Once done then you can itterate over each of the images ([Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) and set their width/height if appropriate

So here is a possible solution for what you need to do, with comments:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.myImg'), // Fetch all images wih the 'myImg' class
    imageArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(images); // Use Array.prototype.slice.call to convert the NodeList to an array

imageArray.forEach(function (img) { // Now itterate over each image in the array
   if (img.width < 50) { // If the width is less than 50
       img.style.setAttribute('height', '100px'); // Set the height and width
       img.style.setAttribute('width', '200px');
   }  
});
```

You will also need to make sure that the code will be executed, if you are using jQuery, put the code above in an `document ready function`, or if you are going to use the button which you currently have. Then put the javascript above into the `myFunction` function your buttons onclick event would call.

Answer (score 0):

Change your id to class since id is unique for each element.

Then to change everything in the class do something like

```
function change(x) {
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName(x);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.width ="100px";
    }
}
```

Comment: He only wants to update the width/height if the width is < 50px.